# Search value in PHP multidimentional array from xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml, search

I have an xml file which I've been trying to search through in PHP. The XML contains rooms and the months  they're available to move into. Here is the xml:

```
<rooms>
    <room>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>room1</name>
        <desc>description1</desc1>
        <date>10-2014</date>
    </room>
    <room>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>room2</name>
        <desc>description2</desc1>
        <date>09-2014</date>
    </room>
    <room>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>room3</name>
        <desc>description3</desc1>
        <date>12-2014</date>
    </room>
    <room>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>room4</name>
        <desc>description4</desc1>
        <date>10-2014</date>
    </room>
</rooms>
```

So, from reading other posts on stackexchange I've managed to do the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./inc/rooms.xml');

$rooms = $xml->room;

$room = array();

foreach ($rooms as $unsortedroom){

    $room[] = $unsortedroom;

}
```

And $room is now supposedly a multidimensional array and displays as the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => room1
            [desc] => description1
            [date] => 10-2014
    )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => room2
            [desc] => description2
            [date] => 09-2014
    )
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => room3
            [desc] => description3
            [date] => 12-2014
    )
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => room4
            [desc] => description4
            [date] => 10-2014
    )
)
```

My question is how can I search through this array to display all arrays inside the array which have the date 10-2014, for instance? So a new array would look like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => room1
            [desc] => description1
            [date] => 10-2014
    )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => room4
            [desc] => description4
            [date] => 10-2014
    )
)
```

I've tried so many codes on here that I couldn't possibly copy and paste all those I've tried as it'd take all day. Been trying it for the last three days. None of them seem to be working. Starting to think maybe it's impossible. I'd be extremely grateful for your comments on what I could do. It's probably really easy. I dunno... Anyways, if anyone can help me with this, it'd relieve me of so much frustration.

Comment: NB: Your XML doesn't validate -- you're opening `<desc>` tags but closing `<desc1>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Example:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

Just noticed you're using an object in an array let me update.

**Update**

Something like this should do the trick

```
function arraySearch($array, $needle)
{
   foreach($array as $key => $obj)
   {
      if ( $obj->date === $needle )
         return $key; // or what ever you want to return $obj to return the whole object.
   }
   return false;
}
```

Call this function like this:

```
$arr[] = arraySearch($yourxmlarray, "10-2014");
```

Update 2:

Tested it this works now:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('rooms.xml');

$rooms = $xml->room;
$room = array();
foreach ($rooms as $unsortedroom) {
    $room[] = $unsortedroom;
}

function arraySearch($array, $needle) {
    foreach($array as $key => $obj) {
        if ( $obj->date == $needle )
            $returnarr[] = $obj; // or what ever you want to return $obj to return the whole object.
        return $returnarr;
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(arraySearch($room, "10-2014"));
```

Comment: Hi. This has returned: Array ( [0] => )

Comment: Hi. Thanks. This helped a lot. Got it working!!!!! It feels so good after so many days trying!  :-)

Comment: @StijnBernards You're doing a lot of unneeded work here -- it would be much easier to iterate through $rooms and do the search then: `foreach ($rooms as $r) { if ($r->date == '10-2014') { $filtered_rooms[] = $r; } }`

Comment: @ialarmedalien I know the $key is obsolete but functions are easier to use if you want to use it again, and the return false is easier to use if you want to just check if a value exists.

Comment: If you're using a function, array_filter is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
example:

```
$choosen=array();
for($a=0;a<count($room);$a++)
     if($room[$a]->date == $date)
          $choosen[]=$a;
```

**Should** prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

If you want function:

```
function search($arr,$needle){
    $choosen=array();
    for($a=0;a<count($room)$a++)
        if($room[$a]->date == $date)
            $choosen[]=$a;
    return $choosen;
}
```

Comment: If you look at his question you can see it's an object inside an array and he is trying to get only the objects where they key data = a value. Array search wont work.

Comment: @Stijn Bernards OK sorry, bad answer :(

Comment: but not tested :d, and it is the same as your but you **return false** if not found I **return empty array** :D (+1 for your answer)

Comment: always nice to see things from anothers perspective huh? ^^